# ansible - If files has different values then update them, otherwise ignore

Tags: bash, ansible, config, app-config

I have been struggling to get this logic correct now for weeks .. What I am trying to do is create an ansible playbook that will install my application on remote hosts ... I have that bit working ...

Now the problem is, like with all app installs it means i need to do a sanity check and make sure that my config is correct.

One of the things I am struggling with is if i have a massive chunk of text (like the one below i need to make sure that the values in that are correct

I am using the Ansible Replace and Lineinfile modules for other things but i dont think it is correct to use those for what I am trying to achieve with this issue I am having ... Has anyone else done something like this where you have a playbook looking at a file and only if the value is not correct update it

```
        <Set name="env"><SystemProperty name="address" default="0.0.0.0"/></Set>
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="https" default="6328" /></Set>
        <Set name="idle">3</Set>
        <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="http" default="-1568"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorDelta"><Property name="ssol" default="9524"/></Set>
        <Set name="PriorityDelta"><Property name="ssl34" default="9635"/></Set>
        <Set name="Size">15874</Set>
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to manipulate xml file yourself with replace and linefile, this is dangerous, use template module (with thinking to "xmlify" string) or xml module

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want all the configs to be the *same*? Then you should just `copy` the file, and if it was already same it shouldn't touch it. Idempotence. If you mean something more complex, please clarify/elaborate in your original post. The `template` module is certainly your friend as well, if values need to be target-specific.

Comment: I need to update certain values from the default config post upgrade .. I dont want to just copy over a file that has the values because then if something was added lets day a new System Property by the vendor in the new package then it will get missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what I want best thing to do is use templates.... Get the new files, update as needed.... Save them in templates and move across....

Answer (score 1):

The elegant solution would probably be to just replace the values with {{ variables }} and then let ansible write the correct values with the [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) module. If your files adhere to some kind of standard (the example looks like XML?), can you use the [xml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html) module?

Otherwise, yeah, I can't think of a better idea than lineinfile/replace either..

---

EDIT to add xml example:

I'm no xpath expert, but I suppose something like this would (sort of) work..

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Sanity Checks
    xml:
      path: file.xml
      xpath: /Set[@name='port']/SystemProperty[@name='https']
      attribute: default
      value: "1000"
```

Comment: XML looks like the best to be honest ... I cant seem to get the syntax correct tho .. If i wanted to make sure those values above are correct how would the syntax look?

Comment: @zoomer See my edit. Note that this would be somewhat verbose for my tastes, you'd have to extract every value you want to check with an xpath. I'll recomment the template module once again, it's the far more elegant solution here.

Comment: Ok, I will have to look at how to use that template module

Comment: So templates is not going to work .. Really Templates is just a glorified copy command where you have a file "built" and you move it across .. I will try and get the XML working properly